# Makefile negative wildcard

Tags: makefile

I use to make use of wildcards in a Makefile in order to select all the files that end with an *.c* suffix in its name. That looks like that `SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)`. In other parts of the Makefile `SRCS` is used.

What I need to do now is to prevent a given file to be included in the SRCS variable. The way I found to do is combine the shell directive with some console commands: `SRC :=$(shell find . -name "*.c" | grep -v "file_to_exclude.c" | xargs)`

That works fine, but I would like to know whether there is some other  more elegant way than that one using only wildcards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the *$(filter-out P,T)* command...

```
SRCS := $(filter-out icky-file.c,$(wildcard *.c))
```

Of course, using shell script is pretty much taking things to another level, as then you're not constrained by Make's commands.

Got a bunch of non-wants?

```
NOWANTS := one.c two.c three.c
SRCS := $(filter-out $(NOWANTS),$(wildcard *.c))
```

Comment: On Linux, install `make-doc`, then check out the full documentation in `/usr/share/doc/make-doc`.  or....   [online make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)